# How to replace text from Row name in R

Tags: r

Currency Name

ISO Code

Base Currency

Decimal Points

Accounting Rates as of 11/1/03

Accounting Rates as of 12/1/03

Accounting Rates as of 1/1/04

I have column names like this (270 columns) where I want to replace Accounting Rates as of using gsub however, I am not able to do it.

```
Fxfile[1,] <- gsub("Accounting Rates as of ","",Fxfile[1,])
```

Comment: Try out `rownames(Fxfile) <- gsub("Accounting Rates as of ", "", rownames(Fxfile))` for new row names and `colnames(Fxfile) <- gsub("Accounting Rates as of ", "", colnames(Fxfile))` for new column names

Answer (score 1):

Column names are not the values of the first row. So just as ANG mentioned it, you should use the `colnames()` function which use the named attributes given to each column. (Attributes are "advanced" feature in R, yet quite useful)
Try out this:

```r
colnames(Fxfile) <- gsub("Accounting Rates as of ","",colnames(Fxfile))
```

PS: for future use, please write your question according to the Best practice guide for asking a good question in Stackoverflow. I answered this question as I understood it, do not hesitate to correct any misunderstanding from my part.